# Посоветуйте плагин выбора даты въезда и выезда из отеля на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, поиск-библиотек

Верстаю сайт отеля и нужно добавить плагин с выбором даты заезда и выезда, скажите пожалуйста, что это за плагин? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поищите [Datepicker](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=datepicker&clid=1955453&banerid=6301000000%3A5bc88f5f1e41a400143feeda&win=355&lr=4). Посмотрите визуальную и функциональную его часть и подключайте который больше понравится.

Comment: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#example-range

Comment: Как вариант, зайдите на подобный сайт, посмотрите как там сделано, можно аккуратно стянуть

Comment: Это задание от fsd https://www.figma.com/file/MumYcKVk9RkKZEG6dR5E3A/FSD-education-program.-The-2nd-task?node-id=18370%3A2  смысл в том чтобы самому переделать какой нибудь из готовых плагинов, но если хотите слизать то вот пример чужой реализации https://github.com/SohtR/toxinHotelUiKit/tree/master/src

Answer (score 1):

Готового плагина JQuery с нужной вам стилизацией нет.

Попробуйте взять какой-нибудь общий плагин JQuery (например, AIR DATEPICKER http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/) и стилизовать его элементы под требования вашей верстки. Это можно будет сделать в css или при помощи параметров options в javascript.

Еще могу посоветовать пройти бесплатный курс https://www.fullstack-development.com/front-end-education, там как раз учат верстать подобные плагины JQuery.